# Android browser intent opening playstore instead of app

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, deep-linking

I am using the following intent url in my website to open my android app:

```
intent:<someContextForTheApp>#Intent;scheme=<appScheme>;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;S.browser_fallback_url=<urlToAppPageInPlaystore>;end
```

The app contains an appropriate intent filter to accept the above mentioned target scheme. The browser fallback url is a link to the playstore page for my app. So when the user clicks on this intent url- if the app is installed it should open the app; and if the app is not installed it should open the playstore page.

This flow was working fine up until recently. Suddenly this seems to be broken- now it opens playstore every time.. even if app is installed. I dont understand why it's not opening the app even though the app is installed.

What is extremely weird is that i created an .html file with this very same intent url as a link. And when i click on that link in the .html file, the app does open. It works in this .html file but it doesn't work for my website. Does anyone know what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need an explicit `Intent`, try adding your app's package name like this:

```
intent:<someContextForTheApp>#Intent;scheme=<appScheme>;package=your.app.package;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;S.browser_fallback_url=<urlToAppPageInPlaystore>;end
```